# Calling a page from one frame into another doesn't run my jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameset

I have a page that has a content specific menu bar on it.  This page has an iframe that loads the actual content into it, which i then run a height and width jquery function on to fill the remainder of the window. The code works fine in all major browsers.  However, this menubar/content page is loaded into a frame.  In Chrome, Opera and Safari it works, however in Firefox it calls the page into the "content" frame, then doesn't run my function on the iframe.

external jquery code: [resize.js](http://www.rodbikes.com/js/resize.js)

test page: [test-main.html](http://www.rodbikes.com/catalog/8-ball/test-main.html)

see it in a frame!: http://www dot rodbikes.com - the link on the left, "test, ignore me" will load the test page into the frame. (my edit broke the links again, sorry)

I know frames are gross, the shop owner wants to keep them. I know my html code doesn't validate properly, when i did get the code for those few pages to validate (using HTML 4.01 Frameset) I had the same problem.

**More Info:**

I wrote 2 functions for sizing the iframe and the div that contains it so they will fill the complete browser window, no matter the viewing size. This lives in the head:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(setheight);
    $(setwidth);
    </script>
```

which calls this from an external .js file:

```
function setheight() {
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#one') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 119)+'px'});

     $('#uno') .css({'height': (($(window).height()) - 119)+'px'});
});
}

function setwidth(){


if ($('frame[name=content]', parent).length) {  
     $('#uno') .css({'width': (($(window).width()) - 171)+'px'});

    }
     else {
        $('#uno') .css({'width': (($(window).width()) - 4)+'px'});
     }
}
```

What I'm finding in OSX firefox is the iframe not having its style updated. When I load the page into a frame its height and width are just whatever stock iframe height/width the browser uses.

I also have the same code as above, except with

```
$(window).resize(function()
```

added so that if the window is resized, the style should update dynamically.
That function is called

```
function move() {
```

and the call to it is the first thing in the body:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(move);
</script>
```

Again, this isn't happening in firefox when in a frame.

Comment: I don't see any obvious differences between the standalone test page and when it's in a frame. Also, some code snippets (with references to where they can be found on the live site) and more detailed explanation of what's not working on the code level would make the question much easier to understand and answer.

Comment: I found a sort of solution.  If i put the javascript directly into the page i'm loading it will work fine.  I'd like to put it in an external file so I could change all of them at once, but alas.  I'm assuming I could fix it by calling the .js in the parent frame and using the frames getElementById work around.